# Unable to Format USB Drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, format

I have a 4.1 GB USB drive that has become unusable now. It previously had a Live version of Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I tried formatting it a couple of times through different techniques on GParted and the Disks Utility. None of them worked properly
Gparted would tell me that a Partition Table was required. When I tried creating a partition table, it would give me a I/O error. When I tried the Discs utility, I would get a 'No Media Found' error.

I tried using the Ignore option on GParted tool.

Now whenever I start GParted, I get a error popup saying

> Input/output error during read on /dev/sdc

The Window is titled "Libparted Bug Found!"
sdc is the USB drive.

Screenshot after clicking on Ignore:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Here is the easy answer:

1. Open `gparted`
2. Select the correct device in the menu <kbd>Devices</kbd>
3. Go to <kbd>Device</kbd> → <kbd>Create Partition Table</kbd>
4. Choose `msdos`
5. If that fails, throw away the USB stick: *It's broken.*  **:-(**
6. Now format
7. If that fails, throw away the USB stick: *It's broken.*  **:-(**

Answer (score 0):

I got this hint from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2084152

Try one or both.

> 1. Since I have an extended partition containing many logical partitions including swap and boot, I used a USB install of GParted to
>      add the label "lba".
> 2. I booted into Windows Vista and ran chkdsk /f twice. The first time showed a lot of errors / bad sectors but the second run was clean.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a ubuntu program however https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/ is confirmed to be very good by most manufacturers and has gotten me out of situations sd card related. Also failing that you may want to do a low level format of the sd

Answer (score 0):

using `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`

folow the help, using `o` option to create a new partition table

after that you can use Disk Utility or GPart to format you flashdisk

Alternative way:

```
sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdc
mklabel msdos
```

If success, continue to use Disk Utilities
Good luck!

Comment: I get this (its on a different port now, hence sdb):  
  
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`  
  
`WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'!`  
  
`The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.`

Comment: instead of fdisk: 

    sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdc
    mklabel msdos

If success, continue to use Disk Utilities
Good luck!